# Importing files from Dropbox using API v2 to a server(web-to-web)

Tags: laravel, api, dropbox

I am trying to implement Dropbox on my website and so far I've been able to **upload, fetch file metadata, user details and also download the file on my local machine(using the Dropbox API v2).**

But, I would like to import the file directly from Dropbox and upload it to the server to be processed further....I'm able to generate the link for the chosen file using the ["Chooser"](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#javascript)

[Dropbox API explorer](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/) lists all the possible APIs dropbox can provide. 
To build the website I'm using **laravel 5.6.17**

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you stuck on exactly? From the description, it sounds like you don't even need to use the API itself. Once you have the link from the Chooser, you can pass the link to the server and then download the linked file directly on the server.

Comment: I can retrieve the direct link from "chooser", I'm having a hard time to figure out how to import that file to my website

Comment: If you have a direct link for a file, you can download it using whatever HTTPS client you prefer. E.g., using `curl` on the command line, that would just look like `curl "<DIRECT LINK>" -o out.txt`.

Comment: Yes thanks Greg I figured out that part. Is there a possible way of choosing a dropbox folder and uploading it to a server without using "chooser".

Comment: You could implement this using [the full Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation) without the Chooser, but it would be more work.